# GParted bricked my USB Drive

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, usb-drive, gparted

I tried to use GParted to rename my USB Drive. Everything appeared to run smoothly, but when I removed the drive and reinserted it, it wouldn't mount.

I can see the USB initialisation in `dmesg`, and see the drive in `lsusb`; however nothing shows up `fdisk`, `ls /dev/` or GParted.

Is there anything I can do to bring this drive back to life?

Answer (score 0):

First, fdisk won't show your USB without root privileges. Type:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Assuming you have only a hardrive, you should see sda and sdb, where your usb would be sdb.

Relabelling your USB shouldn't have caused gparted to alter the file system table. Try to mount it manually trough commandline:

Assuming your usb partition is sdb1 (change the letter or the number according with the output of the previous command) try to mount the device in a local folder (create it first):

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /home/yourusernameher/usbtest/
```

As a last resort, try to check the integrity of the filesystem in the usb:

```
fsck /dev/sdb1
```